# How to identify the checked radio button by using getElementsByName?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getelementsbyname

I have a form `fontVortMetodo`, which I declared as

```
var fM = document.forms["fontVortMetodo"];
```

The user has the choice to submit the form to one of three PHP pages. I let him make the choice first by radio buttons with the name `select`. Then he should press a button, which fires the result of the form elements to the selected page.

For this firing I used the function

```
function destinu() {
  if (fM.elements("select")[0].checked) {
    fM.action = "private_php/Zamenhofa.php";
  } else if (fM.elements("select")[1].checked) {
    fM.action = "private_php/intereuropeco.php";
  } else if (fM.elements("select")[2].checked) {
    tutm = true;
    fM.action = "private_php/tutmondeco.php";
  }
}
```

There was this error:

> `TypeError`: `fM.elements("select")[0].checked` is not a function".

Maybe I should try

```
var destiny = getElementsByName("select")
```

and then proceed with `if (destiny[0].checked)` or `if (destiny[0].checked == true)`.

I don’t know jQuery, which somebody advised me to use, and also for JavaScript I have no reference text. Where can I find a good tutorial for jQuery, although I prefer to do everything by using JavaScript pure?

Comment: typing error: getElementsByName("elekt") = getElementsByName("select")

Comment: I tried, but the block was not in reach. I failed. All "elekt"'s were already changed, when I got a message, that more correcting was impossible, because somebody already answered. However I see no answer. This is just the twofold gap, I wrote about.

Answer (score 0):

## Using pure JS

- Use `dataset` attribute to store the action.
- Use this selector `[name="select"]:checked` to get the checked radio button.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e)  {
  e.preventDefault();  
  var checked = document.querySelector('[name="select"]:checked');
  
  var action = checked.dataset.action;  
  var form = document.querySelector('#fontVortMetodo');
  
  form.setAttribute('action', action);
  
  var tutm = checked.dataset.tutm !== undefined;
  
  console.log("Action: " + action);
  console.log('Is tutm: '+ tutm);
  
  //$form.submit();  // This is if you need to to submit the form.
});
```

```html
<form id='fontVortMetodo' name='fontVortMetodo'>
  <input type='radio' name='select' data-action="private_php/Zamenhofa.php">
  <input type='radio' name='select' data-action="private_php/intereuropeco.php">
  <input type='radio' name='select' data-action="private_php/tutmondeco.php" data-tutm='true'>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand jQuery. 
I am 79 years old and have no time left to learn another programming language, if even Javascript is still a very difficult subject for me.
As I wrote already, that somebody advised me to use jQuery, I prefer to use pure Javascript. This can't be so difficult.